# Vue JS - selected Dropdown value of an input in a create/edit dialog doesn´t appear

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Form in a Dialog with a dropdown list to select an element. When I select the element, the element doesn´t appear on the input field but when I submit the value is there.

I don´t know why but I have the same problem with Calendar Input

I just check the documentation, try different things but it doesn´t work

Dialog

```
    <Dialog 
      v-model:visible="displayNewDelivery"
      :style="{ width: '30vw' }" 
      :modal="true" 
      class="p-fluid"
      :value="delivery"   
      header="Add New Delivery">
    
      <div class = "card p-fluid">
        <div class="field">
          <strong><label for="ddate">Delivery Date</label></strong>
          <Calendar inputId="basic" v-model="date" autocomplete="off" />
          
        
        </div>

        <div class="field">
          <strong><label for="dw">Delivery Weight</label></strong>
            <InputNumber id="dw" v-model.trim="delivery.DeliveryWeight" required="true" autofocus  />
        </div>

        <div class="field">
          <strong><label for="lon">Final Storage</label></strong>
          <Dropdown
                id="dfinal"
                v-model="delivery.FinalStorage"
                :options="storages"
                option-label="designation"
                option-value="id"
                placeholder="Select a Storage"/>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
          <strong><label for="ttl">Time To Load</label></strong>
            <InputNumber id="ttl" v-model.trim="delivery.TimeToLoad" required="true" autofocus  />
        </div>

        <div class="field">
          <strong><label for="str">Time To Unload</label></strong>
            <InputNumber id="str" v-model.trim="delivery.TimeToUnload" required="true" autofocus  />
        </div>
      </div>
      <template #footer>
      <Button
        label="Save"
        @click="addDelivery"
        icon="pi pi-check"
        class="p-button-outlined"
      />
    </template>
    </Dialog>
```

storages

```
  {
    "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
    "designation": "string",
    "location": {
      "id": {
        "value": "string"
      },
      "latitude": "string",
      "longitude": "string",
      "altitude": "string",
      "address": {
        "id": {
          "value": "string"
        },
        "street": "string",
        "door": "string",
        "floor": "string",
        "postalCode": "string",
        "city": {
          "id": {
            "value": "string"
          },
          "number": 0,
          "name": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "chargingSystems": [
      {
        "id": {
          "value": "string"
        },
        "chargingTime": "string"
      }
    ],
    "active": true
  }
]

delivery.FinalStorage: string
```

Comment: Which UI framework are you using?

Comment: Im using VUE JS with primevue components